# What was this movie about an isolated community that came out earlier this century?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am trying to identify a film that I saw a trailer for around 5 or more years ago. This century at least. The film was about a peaceful, low technology (maybe rural,) community isolated by a forest or perhaps a wall. I don't think any of the actors or anyone else associated with it were well known and I don't think the film was popular. I think it was American made but I'm not sure. It was similar to *The Village,* but I think the place was peaceful and without a threat from outside. It kind of had a similar conveyance of perspective as in the book *Phoenix Without Ashes.* I wanted to see the film but it dropped out of the theaters quickly. The recent film "The Maze Runner" reminded me of it. The film in question had at least one pair of young people, a man and a woman, who were protagonists. I think the young man said he was going to venture outside of the community into the unknown dangers, hence, the film's conflict. This missing knowledge has bothered me for a while. I'm sure you can relate.

Comment: Funny - because when I saw this I immediately thought "The Village" - but as you say it was similar, I guess it can't be.

Comment: @HorusKol pedantic[on] I would said "The Village" is pretty similar to "The Village" pedantic[off]

Comment: Can you recall any known actors/faces in that movie? Anything else you can remember from the theatrical trailer or whatever, like, why she wanted to go out?

Comment: I don't recall any of the actors. I think they were relative unknowns at the time, otherwise I would have remembered them.  I think the young male protagonist was simply curious about the outside world, at least in the trailer. Of all the suggestions, their situation seemed most like those in "The Village" but it is definitely not that movie. I have seen it. When I first saw the trailer for the movie in question I thought I would learn more about it and eventually see it but it disappeared too quickly and now I regret not making more of an effort to watch it.

Comment: Are you sure it was a movie?  Could it be that you actually just visited Amish Country?

Comment: What part of this movie made it related to science-fiction or fantasy?

Comment: Leaving this open, dystopian/post-apocalyptic is well within the genre limits of this SE.

Comment: see OP confirmation comment (under non-linked account) for corresponding answer below

Answer (score 5):

I think I discovered the movie. I am not certain but I have a feeling that the "*Stardust*" trailer was the item in question. The first twenty-five seconds of the trailer seems to fit my memory. After that the trailer takes a turn that reveals a sizeable budget for the film. That could be the reason that I never saw it. It just looked like an over-effected movie with an uninteresting plot. It did have Robert De Niro and Michelle Pfeiffer in it though. Thanks for everyone's help. I will sleep a little better now. ;-) Tony

Comment: Could be, possibly (the question isn't very detailed), but it doesn't match "I don't think any of the actors or anyone else associated with it were well known" with a cast including Peter O'Toole, Robert de Niro, and Michelle Pfeiffer! (PS: Stardust is an *excellent* film.)

Comment: @Rand this seems to be the OP.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Is there any way the mods can confirm whether this is in fact the OP or not?

Comment: @Möoz Check the avatars; this does indeed appear to be the OP. (I wasn't a mod at the time of those previous comments!) I've now upvoted this answer, in an attempt to make it float to the top.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Nice, also, you're welcome to upvote [_my_ answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/114594/21267) too :p

Answer (score 4):

How sure are you that the setting was low-tech and/or rural? I ask, because I know a couple that fit the question but that are somewhat high-tech and enclosed.

The first act of [The Island](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0399201/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) takes place in a bunker, inhabited by people who believe the world has been devastated. A young couple escape from the bunker and (of course) learn the awful truth.

[The City of Ember](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0970411/) is set in an underground city whose lights are failing. A young couple have to leave the city to find the means to save it.

As a wild guess, [Æon Flux](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0402022/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_19). THat town is surrounded by a wall and a forest.

TVTropes have a page on [The Wall Around the World](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheWallAroundTheWorld) - you might find your movie there. *Usual TVTropes productivity-warning applies.*

Comment: I don't know if there was any high technology. I don't remember seeing any. Two characters were talking near the edge of a forest and one of them was saying he was going into it even though no one else dares to. My impression was that he was some kind of hunter/gatherer type. Thanks for the movie suggestions. I am familiar with all of them and I went and looked at each of their trailers to see if I could be confusing this movie with the rest of them, but I wasn't. Isn't this a great sub-category in Science Fiction?

Answer (score 3):

*[Red Riding Hood (2011)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Riding_Hood_(2011_film))* seems to somewhat fit the bill:

- It was a movie set in a secluded village

  - Separated by forest and a wall
- Low-technology village
- Main protagonists - man and woman
- Man ventures out of the safety of the village out into the dangers of the forest
- Released this century, in 2011

Here is its [official trailer on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PM8V3cHdSC4):

Answer (score 0):

The movie is "The Giver". From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Giver_(film)):

> Following a calamity, referred to as The Ruin, society is reorganized into a series of communities, and all memories of the past are held by one person, the Receiver of Memory. Since the Receiver of Memory is the only individual in the community with the memories from earlier times, he must advise the Chief Elder and the other Elders on the decisions for the community. The Receiver of Memory and his assistant are also the only ones endowed with color vision (color blindness being a side effect of the daily, emotion-numbing drug injections imposed on everybody else).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Please note that if you copy text from elsewhere, [you must cite your source](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps you saw a movie adaptation of *Taken* by Erin Bowman?

Comment: According to [Erin Bowman's website](http://www.embowman.com/extras/faq/), the *Taken* series has not been adapted to a movie